# drawing lines bottom of form

Tags: c#, opengl

How can I draw a horizontal box at the bottom of my viewport in OpenGL? This is drawing it at the top. What's wrong?

```
var H = window height;
var len = 20;

gl.Vertex3d(0, H - len, 0);       //top     left
gl.Vertex3d(Width, H - len, 0);   //top     right
gl.Vertex3d(Width, H + len, 0);   //bottom  left
gl.Vertex3d(0, H + len, 0);       //bottom  right
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL's default coordinate space has Y pointing upward. You can change that, or you can change your vertices, depending on what you're going to do and what you're used to. In the case you've posted, where it's just a single quad, you can probably just change the vertices and do something like this:

```
gl.Vertex3d(0, len, 0);       //top     left
gl.Vertex3d(Width, len, 0);   //top     right
gl.Vertex3d(Width, -len, 0);   //bottom  left
gl.Vertex3d(0, -len, 0);       //bottom  right
```

If you're drawing a lot of other stuff, you can set the current transform matrix as you need to before drawing (and possibly restore it afterwards), by doing something along the lines of:

```
gl.matrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gl.ortho(left, right, top, bottom, near, far); // Note reversal of top and bottom
```